# Get local IP address of VPN gateway

Tags: vpn, routing

I'm connected to my employer's VPN, and I'm trying to manually add routes to my workstation to send traffic for a hosts through the VPN. How can I discover the local IP address for my VPN gateway?

*TMI: I'm told that manually specifying routes is necessary because Linux doesn't support dns-based routes. (I'm in the dark.) I can confirm, at least, that my requests to the target host consistently timeout.*

Having read [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1407570/116235), I suppose that I need to discover this IP address and then execute:

```
route add -host <Target Server IP> gw <Local IP of VPN Gateway>
```

My VPN client is *Cisco AnyConnect*. I've tried to look for the gateway by running `ip route | grep default`, but that gives me only my wifi router's address. Running `ip a` gives me this information:

```
5: cscotun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1390 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet [AN IPv4 ADDRESS]/32 brd [AN IP ADDRESS] scope global cscotun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 [AN IPv6 ADDRESS]/126 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 [AN IPv6 ADDRESS]/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

> TMI: I'm told that manually specifying routes is necessary because Linux doesn't support dns-based routes. (I'm in the dark.) I can confirm, at least, that my requests to the target host consistently timeout.

This is partially true, but not exactly in the way you imply.

IP routes are *never* DNS-based, as the name lookup is a separate step from route lookup – by the time the OS needs to check the routing table, it has no way to associate it with the original domain name that was used.

So there is no difference between Windows and Linux in this regard. Corporate VPNs usually work by providing specific IP-based routes for all hosts that the user may need to access.

Where Windows and Linux *do* differ is in being able to "route" *the DNS lookups themselves* to different DNS servers based on their suffix. Linux only supports this if 'systemd-resolved' is being used (and the VPN app cooperates with it), or if manual configuration of additional apps is done (e.g. using dnsmasq), while Windows has it "native".

(Many people do not yet consider systemd-provided functionality to be "built-in".)

Often corporate VPNs use "split DNS", where a domain like 'foo.example.com' may give different results – i.e. resolve to a private IP address when the VPN DNS servers are queried, bt a public IP address otherwise. In this case, you don't need IP routes to be domain-based, instead you need the DNS queries to use the correct DNS server.

> My VPN client is Cisco AnyConnect. I've tried to look for the gateway by running ip route | grep default, but that gives me only my wifi router's address.

Yes, your VPN doesn't set up a "default" route; this is usually normal for corporate VPNs. (In fact if there *was* a default route via the VPN, you wouldn't be having this problem in the first place, as *all* traffic would go through the VPN anyway!)

However, also note that AnyConnect uses a 'tun' interface, which is a "layer-3 tunnel" or "point-to-point" tunnel. With this tunnel type, the remote gateway is actually irrelevant (as there's no layer-2 header which could be affected by it), and it should be enough for a route to only specify the device.

For example:

```
ip route add <TargetServerIP>/32 dev cscotun0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @user1686. I've run both `ip route add $MY_SRV_IP/32 dev cscotun0` and `ip route add 52.9.0.0/16 dev cscotun0` now, but no reference to my TargetServerIp shows up in the output of `ip route`, and my attempts to ssh to TargetServerIp still timeout. (Could it be because there's already a route specified as `52.85.129.0/23 dev cscotun0 proto unspec scope link`?) Do you have an idea what I should check now?

Comment: Any hints? I face the same issue, the route is not added / not shown. I suspect maybe the cisco is preventing updates?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want "the local IP address for your VPN gateway" as that would not route the traffic.  In fact the first [AN IPv4 ADDRESS] third line of your second text snipped shows this.

The first thing I would try is to not use an IP address, but just the interface, eg with a command like

```
  ip route add [IP ADDRESS OR ROUTE/XX] dev cscotun0
```

If you want to find the REMOTE IP address of your VPN gateway - which is needed to pass traffic through it, something like the below might work

```
  ip route | grep "cscotun0" | grep "link" | cut -f1 -d" "
```

(I've not tested exactly this as I only have an OpenVPN tun device.  The idea is to find the directly connected route associated with the device to get the remote end - this does assume that the cscotun0 device is a point-to-point device)

I'm not sure what "Linux doesn't support dns-based routes" means.  You can specify a domain name in an "ip" or "route" command and it will certainly work.  What it won't do is update the remote IP address if the DNS changes once the command has run - you would need to rerun the command.  Any other behaviour would not make sense as it would mean a DNS lookup for every packet traversing the router which would be incredibly slow and wasteful of resources.

Comment: Thanks, @davidgo. I'm not sure where to go from here: I've run `ip route add $MY_SRV_IP/32 dev cscotun0`, and now (1) my ssh attempts still timeout and (2) `$MY_SRV_IP` doesn't still show up in the output of `ip route`. When I grep `ip route` with the command that you prescribed, I in fact get 147 distinct lines.